# Where did the reading for 鏡 in 眼鏡 come from?

Tags: readings

I looked up the reading for `鏡` in `眼{め}鏡{がね}` on jisho.org [here](http://jisho.org/search/%E9%8F%A1%20%23kanji), but I could not find `がね`, only `かがみ`,`キョウ`, and `ケイ`.

Where did that reading come from?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

「ガネ」 is not a reading for 鏡.  The issue here is that the word 眼鏡 has a [熟字訓]{じゅく・じ・くん}; that is, a reading applied to the entire word, not to the individual parts.  In fact, you can see 眼鏡 [at the top of this list here](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%86%9F%E5%AD%97%E8%A8%93#.E7.94.9F.E6.B4.BB.E7.94.A8.E5.93.81).

You can find many other examples of words with 熟字訓 on that same page.

In fact, even in writing your topic, you typed the word as 眼​{め}鏡​{がね} which incorrectly associates the hiragana with the kanji.  In cases of 熟字訓, I like to enclose the whole reading in `« »`.  So I would type it in as [眼鏡]​{«めがね»} and it displays like so [眼鏡]{«めがね»}.  But that's just my preference for how to do it.

Answer (score 4):

To build on istrasci's answer, the がね is [rendaku](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rendaku) for かね, with a basic meaning of "metal" (and a more common kanji spelling of 金): "eye" + "metal" in reference to the metal frame of eyeglasses.  Modern glasses can use various materials for the frame, but earlier, metal was the main (only?) material used.